# Dynamically created webpage without a subdomain

Tags: subdomain, cloudflare

Im having a really hard time configuring cloudflare properly so any help is much appreciated.

I have a web application that creates a unique database for each user, example :

the application is installed on `example.com`. Once the user `user1` signs up, its login url will be `user1.example.com` you can see an example of what I'm talking about if you open an account on [www.activecampaign.com](http://www.activecampaign.com)

Now the issue is that once I set up cloudflare DNS `example.com` is working, I have a forum on a subdomain forum.example.com which is working as well because  I've added an A recored for that subdomain on cloudflare but `user1.example.com` is not working

Don't tell me to add an A record for `user1.example.com` because `user1` is not a subdomain. The app just create a unique database for each user same like the activecampaign app does.

Comment: It sure looks like a subdomain from here.

Comment: I edited your question a bit, maybe a bit too much. Feel free to rollback if you disagree.

Answer (score 3):

If you want people to use a URL like that to log in, you need to add a wildcard record:

```
*.example.com IN A $your_server
*.example.com IN AAAA $your_server
```

DNS works this way regardless of what services you are using or what you are using them for.  It *is* a subdomain (says the DNS standard, [RFC1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt)) - it just isn't a different application in your case.

You could also potentially add A and AAAA records for each user, but that is awkward and will become unmanageable, and may allow for valid username discovery.

Comment: Hi, 

First of all thank you for your replay I'm having *.example.com IN A  my server Ip set up properly

Without having cloudflare set up the website is working properly but when i enable cloudflare the user url is not working

Please let me know how i can solve this issue

Best,